# Self-verifying theory! But what can we learn from it?

Tags: logic, soft-question, philosophy, foundations, proof-theory

There is this *seemingly surprising result* that no consistent and sufficiently expressive theory can prove its own consistency. But what would be the actual benefit from knowing that a theory $T$ can do this? (e.g. Dan Willard's self-verifying theory) As I understand, we can encounter one of the following two scenarios:

1. $T$ is consistent and proves its own consistency.
2. $T$ is inconsistent, and because of this, also proves its own consistency.

The outcome is the same. So even if we can prove that $T$ proves its own consistency (do we need a meta theory here?), then we have no way to conclude whether $T$ is actually consistent or not, despite of the given proof. So what have we learned at all?

Is this more a tool to classify the expressive power of a theory than actually talking about its consistency? In the end it is easy to find a theory that proves its own consistency $-$ just take an inconsistent one. What distinguishes Dan Willard's self-verifying theory from such a trivial example? That it is *not obviously* inconsistent?

---

**NOTE:**

Feel free to make a note, whether this question might be better placed in another SE, like philosophy. I honestly do not know if it belongs here.

Comment: Related to this, I'm interested in the question of whether a theory that permits *quantifying over sentences* can transcend Godel's incompleteness theorem by having no models. But I'm by no means an expert.

Comment: @RobertFrost Having no models won't circumvent Godel - that just means the theory is inconsistent, unless you're working in a ridiculously weak proof calculus. As for quantifying over sentences - that actually doesn't add much. Godel's theorem is proven by making use of Godel numbering, which is a way of encoding sentences as numbers. So there (sort of) already *are* sentence-quantifiers.

Comment: @Reese To be fair, that depends on what exactly you can *do* with the sentences you've quantified over. We can of course quantify over Goedel numbers already, but if you (say) add a truth predicate, then this all blows up. So it depends what your signature has for handling sentences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I've always seen it, the Incompleteness Theorem isn't really about consistency so much as "totality". The idea is that the Holy Grail of mathematical foundations was to find a single system of axioms which (a) we believed to be true and (b) could prove everything in math. Godel's Incompleteness demonstrates that this goal is unattainable: there will always be a sentence that is true but unprovable from our axioms, unless we make the mistake of choosing inconsistent axioms. The fact that the sentence in question is "the axioms are consistent" isn't terribly important.

In fact, as I understand it, for some time many mathematicians considered Incompleteness unimportant - the philosophy was that sure, there are true sentences unprovable from (e.g.) ZFC, but they're just pathological things like Con(ZFC) that no one would really care about (for exactly the reasons you pointed out). It wasn't until the Continuum Hypothesis was shown to be independent of ZFC that people really understood that Incompleteness was a serious obstacle for foundational mathematics in general.

Now, of course, independence results have graduated from "obstacle" into "field of interest"; most people have given up on finding that Holy Grail, and instead started enjoying the Holy-Enough Grail that we have in ZFC. In fact, interest has sparked in going the other direction, to *less* powerful theories, like the Somewhat-Holy Grail of ZF (ZFC without the Axiom of Choice).

Comment: So the difference between Dan Willard's self-verifying theory and an obviously inconstistent theory is that we *believe* in the former one, or more precisely: that the former one can be shown to be relatively consistent to ZFC (in which we believe)?

Comment: Also couldn't it be, that a sufficiently expressive theory can prove/disprove anything but your "pathological things like Con(ZFC)"? Wouldn't this be more satisfying than the current status? Of course this needs clarification on what *pathological things* are.

Comment: @M.Winter Re: your first comment, yes, and *vastly less* than ZFC is required to prove its consistency (I would have to check but I believe even $I\Sigma_1$, a tiny fragment of Peano arithmetic, is enough). Re: your second comment, there's no good sense in which that's true - it's not hard to show that for any appropriate theory T, the set of sentences undecidable in T is incomputable! (Otherwise we could build a computable consistent complete extension of T, via a "greedy algorithm" along a list of all sentences.) So you'll always run across surprising examples of undecidable sentences.

Answer (score 1):

Inconsistent theories still generate correct proofs. Take for example naive set theory: Even though it turned out to be inconsistent, the work (for example) of Cantor wasn't erroneous and most results still hold in axiomatic set theory.

The same applies with arithmetics. If a proof of the consistency of arithmetics could exist within arithmetics, the proof may be such that we are convinced of its correctness.  This is because an inconsistent theory proves everything via contradictions, so a proof of consistency might be produced in such a way, or from such a fragment of arithmetics, that we can feel relatively confident about its correctness. In the end we have some intuitions about numbers on which we can base the safety of such a proof.

This was (roughly) the idea of Hilbert: Produce a proof from finitistic methods (methods that we feel confident about their correctness) of the consistency of mathematical theories that can produce most parts of mathematics.

Comment: "This is because an inconsistent theory proves everything via contradiction". Is this some actual result in some sense? I mean i know the usual way to prove an arbitrary result from a contradiction, but is it known, that this is *the only* way?

Comment: @M.Winter "Is this some actual result in some sense?" Yes, it follows from the fact that classical logic allows proof by contradiction (and is called the principle of explosion, or ex falso quodlibet). "is it known, that this is the only way?" I'm not really sure what you're asking, but note that logics not allowing proof by contradiction can have inconsistencies without proving everything (see e.g. paraconsistent logic).

Comment: I mean the following: Do you mean that, in order to derive a contradiction in PA or ZFC (where we do not know if there is any), we necessarily need the concept of *proof by contradiction*? Is this known? This is what I read from "This is because an inconsistent theory proves everything via contradiction"?

Comment: @M.Winter No, what I mean is that the reason (common) inconsistent systems prove everything is because they prove contradictions (for example $\phi\land\lnot\varphi$) and contradictions imply every formula. So it is not completely mysterious to us why inconsistent systems prove everything, hence we have intuitions whether a proof is correct or not, regardless of whether the system is inconsistent.

Comment: @Apostolos Is this the reason why some rare mathematicians (are they called constructivists?) do not like to use proof by contradiction, because it may be hard to see that this is not the proof of a contradiction $\varphi\wedge\neg\varphi$ in disguise?